Mail api dependency is throwing some error

class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html cannot be cast to class javax.activation.DataContentHandler (com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @4f3f5b24; javax.activation.DataContentHandler is in unnamed module of loader org.pf4j.PluginClassLoader @c2e3264).

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.lowcoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>lowcoder-plugins</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>smtpPlugin</artifactId>

    <name>smtpPlugin</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <plugin.id>smtp-plugin</plugin.id>
        <plugin.class>org.lowcoder.plugins.SmtpPlugin</plugin.class>
        <plugin.version>${revision}</plugin.version>
        <plugin.provider>service@lowcoder.org</plugin.provider>
        <plugin.dependencies/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <!--        vertx os async but not mature, used in test -->
        <!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/vertx-mail-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-mail-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.77.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>shade-plugin-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Plugin-Id>${plugin.id}</Plugin-Id>
                                        <Plugin-Class>${plugin.class}</Plugin-Class>
                                        <Plugin-Version>${plugin.version}</Plugin-Version>
                                        <Plugin-Provider>${plugin.provider}</Plugin-Provider>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I tried changing the pom but the problem persists.

@seenukarthi This is a spring boot project using project reactor .

Does that make much of a difference in this case? To me, it seems like the solutions would apply here as well.
